# apply changes to case when on mysql

Tags: mysql

i´m tryin to apply some changes to this query, maybe someone can correcting my query to meke it work.

```
SELECT       
    FECHA_RECEPCION, 
    CASE ID_ESTADO 
        WHEN ESTADO = 'RECHAZADO' THEN ID_ESTADO = ''
        WHEN ESTADO = 'APROBADO' THEN ID_ESTADO = '' 
        ELSE ID_ESTADO
    END AS ID_ESTADO 
FROM RDB
WHERE 
    CI = '3322'
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
CASE
    WHEN ESTADO IN ('RECHAZADO', 'APROBADO') THEN ''
    ELSE ID_ESTADO
END AS ID_ESTADO
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: wow man, that's correct, thats what i need, now i see my mistake, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

CASE WHEN syntax is:
1) CASE VARIABLE WHEN VALUE1 THEN RESULT1 WHEN VALUE2 THEN RESULT2 ... ELSE RESULT END
OR
2) CASE WHEN CONDITION2 THEN RESULT1 WHEN CONDITION2 THEN RESULT2 ... ELSE RESULT END

So, you can use type 2 like that:
CASE WHEN STADO_ARPO_RECHA IN ('RECHAZADO','APROBADO') THEN '' ELSE ID_STADO_MATERIAL END AS ID_STADO_MATERIAL